# I want to display the bill amount for productId on the basis of particular date for'31-jan-2016' and '31-mar-2016'

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to display the bill amount for `productId` on the basis of particular date for '31-jan-2016' and '31-mar-2016' but the query display the Same bill amount for both dates. Suggest a query.

**My query**

```
Select productId, 
  sum(billAmount)as'31jan',
  sum(billAmount)as '31Mar' 
from test 
where billDate='31-jan-2016 '
  and '31-mar-2016' 
group by productId;
```

Comment: I doubt, if this get executed

Comment: You need to atleast provide your sample data and expected output.

Comment: `AND billDate = '31-mar-2016' `?

Comment: The query is executing but the output is not expected.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase

```
  where billDate='31-jan-2016 'and '31-mar-2016'
```

doesn't mean what you think it means.   `'31-mar-2016'` isn't a comparison expression.  You probably want

```
where (billDate='something'  OR  billDate='anotherthing')
```

But, also, your date formatting isn't following the SQL standard. You may want dates formattted as `'2016-03-31'` instead. That's a guess, because you did not mention the data type of your `billDate` column.

Finally, you probably need to study up on how to use `GROUP BY` and `SUM` expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional aggregation seems like one approach to take:

```
Select productId,
       sum(case when billDate = '2016-01-31' then billAmount else 0 end) as amount_20160131,
       sum(case when billDate = '2016-03-31' then billAmount else 0 end) as amount_20160331
from test
where billDate in ('2016-01-31', '2016-03-01')
group by productId;
```

Notes:

- This uses ISO standard date formats, YYYY-MM-DD.
- Only use single quotes for string and date constants, not for column aliases.
- The use of the `case` inside the `sum()` solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff 